# How to redirect to login page if a paramter is missing in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following code in Symfony 3 where some users have the wrong links and Symfony is showing a blank page for it. The code is something like this:

```
/**
   * @Route(
   *   "/account/reset-password/{user_id}/{hash}",
   *   name="reset_password"
   * )
   */
  public function accountResetPasswordAction(Request $request, $user_id, $hash) {}
```

**/account/reset-password/1/abcd** - this will be proper url

**/account/reset-password//abcd** - is there anyway I can redirect this to a login page?

Comment: You should put requirements on the `{user_id}` parameter, forcing something like `\d+` regex. Then it will 404 on the 2nd link you described

Comment: @jasonRoman Sorry mate didn't get you point

Comment: See here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#adding-wildcard-requirements

Comment: Why not fix the link generation instead?

Comment: @goto links are already send to customer for those particular I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways here, depending on your needs.

First, with full control where to send the user.

```
 /**
   * @Route(
   *   "/account/reset-password/{user_id}/{hash}",
   *   name="reset_password"
   * )
   */
  public function accountResetPasswordAction(Request $request, $user_id = null, $hash = null) {
    if (!$user_id || !$hash) {
      return $this->redirectToRoute('your_login_route');
    }
  }
```

---

If you are OK with a `404 page` instead, you can put requirements on those two parameters.

```
/**
  * @Route(
  *   "/account/reset-password/{user_id}/{hash}",
  *   name="reset_password",
  *   requirements={"user_id":"\d+", "hash":"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"}
  * )
  */
```

Comment: I have tried the first way but it doesn't work if the parameter is missing the control doesn't goes in the function itself.

Comment: If you want to cover missing parameters, too, you need a default. I've added that.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY need a 403 instead of a 404, then you should do something like

```
if (null === $user_id) {
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
}
```

Then your firewall should catch this exception and automatically redirect to your login form.

This shortcut is available is Symfony controllers since 2.5 (see here)